# I can't Run python codes in Atom but can run it in visual studios as i have used anconda 3 to download python

Tags: python, visual-studio, cmd, atom-editor, anaconda3

I have downloaded the script package in atom to run python but it gives me this error"
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
[Finished in 0.514s]"

i have download python by using anaconda

python works in the anaconda prompt and runs with visual studio

how to get it work in atom

someone told me if i installed python it will not work with anaconda am confused as am new to all of that any help?

Comment: Did you follow this advice from the script readme? https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script#atom-cant-find-node--ruby--python--my-socks

Comment: Thank you for sending me this link it works now